# Styling by using bootstrap 4 the auto generated login fom by Azure ad bc

Tags: bootstrap-4, azure-ad-b2c

I am using azure ad b2c to get a login page . By azure it's auto genrated and its injected to the body of my html inside a pre-define div element with class name "api". I want to add bootstrap 4 classes to the div element dynamically after the document being ready without js or jquery is that possible ?any hack?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible without JavaScript.